# Create a Magic like Card with Layouts in Android; For a GridView

Tags: android, layout, gridview, background

I'm trying to do something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcPcu.jpg with Layouts in Android. And all i got it's Distorsioned Background ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/43l3Y.png).

If i try to show a simply card, without the gridview; all it's well. And at this time, i'm out of mind. Please Help.

This are my code.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="60dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#ffffff">
</GridView>
```

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/card"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bug_item_set_img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bug_item_set_txt_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bug_item_set_txt_desc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```